# SQL Server timeout on updating one particular table, works fine on other

Tags: sql-server, linq, timeout

I'm using Winforms app. with LINQ and .NET

When using the submitChanges() function on one table I have a timeout error, whatevet the record is to be updated.

On other tables I have no problem.

When using an update query from within SQL Server management Studio, I can update the faulty table !!!

Since the error is about timeout, the software itself souldn't be the culprit, but then,
**Does anybody have an idea of what this problem is?**

Note: This DB is hosted by an ISP, works fine since 2 years and is only 1.6 GB with truncate log on checkpoint.

The problem arouse 1 hour ago! Not after a particular change of my software or the LINK update itself.
YThe problem doesn't come from my computer since a client has the same issue, and i tried from 2 computers (one remote).

Answer (score 1):

Check for blocking and wait type. First in Management Studio, identify the session_id that is executing your query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests;
```

Then run:

```
SELECT wait_type, blocking_session_id 
  FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
  WHERE session_id = x;
```

(Replacing `x` with the spid that is being blocked.)

Comment: Thanks, how do I identify the session_ID?

Comment: Well it should have a command of `UPDATE` in `sys.dm_exec_requests`, and you can check the program name or host name in `sys.dm_exec_sessions` as well.